# delete an element from an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, unset

Ok then. I have a filled array defined like this:

```
$subs = array();
for (...) {
    // extracting of variables $knowledgeLevel, $name, $short, $long
    $subs [] = array (
         'knowledgeLevel' => $knowledgeLevel,
         'name' => $name,
         'shortTheory' => $short,
         'longTheory' => $long
    );
}
```

then I receive a value `$kl`, and I want to eventually delete from the array `$subs` the `element` that has the `knowledgeLevel` equal to `$kl`. I've tried to do so:

```
foreach ( $subs as $subject ) {
    if ($subject['knowledgeLevel'] == $kl) {
        unset ($subject);
    }
}
```

and so

```
foreach ( $subs as $subject ) {
    if ($subject['knowledgeLevel'] == $kl) {
        unset ($subject['knowledgeLevel']);
        unset ($subject['name']);
        unset ($subject['shortTheory']);
        unset ($subject['longTheory']);
    }
}
```

but these don't seem to work.

Comment: Where is `$kl` defined?

Comment: You want to remove an element from `$subs` array? It's a numeric array, not associative. Its elements are associative arrays.

Comment: I have two functions that use the same array (declared as global). `$kl`is the parameter of the second function

Comment: @Mojtaba sorry! Edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop
>   precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by
>   reference.

Use `&` with `foreach ( $subs as &$subject )`

```
foreach ( $subs as &$subject ) 
    if ( $subject['knowledgeLevel'] == $kl ) 
        unset ($subject);
```

Or try this:

> This form will additionally assign the current element's key to the $key
>   variable on each iteration.

```
foreach ( $subs as $key => $subject )
    if ( $subject['knowledgeLevel'] == $kl ) 
        unset( $subs[$key] );
```

Comment: there is no diffrent but I my self choose the second. because its clear.

Comment: @Jannuzzo . welcome to stackoverflow. and let me remind you somthing. lets be a good supporter with upvoting and accepting useful answers.(-:

Comment: @imsiso 'vote up' privilege requires 15 reputation. OP has only 6.

Comment: @AndreyVolk I know but I say it not for now. for all time but he can still accept the answers. btw +1 to you.

Answer (score 0):

`$subject` is not reference to `$subs` it's new variable and with `unset($subject['anything'])` you are not deleting anything from `$subs`

Use `for` loop:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($subs);$i++) {
   if ($subs[$i]['knowledgeLevel'] == $kl) {
       unset ($subs[$i]);
   }
}
```